# Multi-label text classification CNN

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm, sentiment-analysis, multilabel-classification

**Context**

I'm building an Emotion Analysis Neural Net for my final year project, I have decided to use a CNN as there have been some impressive results with CNNs in Emotion Analysis. I wish to be able to make multi-label classifications, such as:

{Joy: 0.92, Humour: 0.67} and {Anger: 0.54, Disgust: 0.65}

I have researched multi-label classification and found this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff    but I am still not sure how to approach.

The article suggests that there are several common approaches to solving multi-label classification problems: OneVsRest, Binary Relevance, Classifier Chains, Label Powerset. The article also mentions under 'Further Improvements' at the bottom of the page that the multi-label problem can be solved using an LSTM.

The Label Powerset approach seems fairly straightforward, and feasible as I will only have 6 or so labels. I would consider using an LSTM if there are any advantages to doing so, though I'm not sure whether the article is suggesting using an LSTM in place of a CNN or a combination of both. I have seen some tutorials and articles around on multi-label classification with CNNs but they are all geared toward image classification.

**Questions**

How can an LSTM be used in combination with a CNN to perform multi-label classification?

Are there any other ways to do multi-label classification with a CNN other than the ones mentioned above that I should consider?

Comment: hopeful bump :)

Comment: My first thought was use the main CNN to produce abstract features, that you then feed into a set of fully-connected networks, one per emotion, to give you the scores. The tricky bit would be setting the training objective. (That didn't seem to quite match any of the options in the article.) See the continual learning idea of ERNIE 2.0 (or any of the ELMO algorithms).

Comment: I think the LSTM would be instead of the CNN?